# Fabric.js create image on Node server after loading canvas from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, fabricjs

I've been racking my brain the last couple of days trying to figure this out. In the app I'm writing, a user can upload two images, one that overlays the other. After placing one image on top of the other, they click a button and the canvas is converted to JSON and sent to a node (express) server. The canvas is then recreated by loading the JSON data to the canvas, calling toDataURL with a multiplier of 2 and writing the data to a png file.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(600, 600);

canvas.loadFromJSON(req.body, function() {
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        multiplier: 2
    });
    imageSrc = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    fs.writeFile('hello.png', imageSrc, 'base64', function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

If I don't use a multiplier (i.e. multiplier is 1), a 600x600px image is created, as expected. But when I set the multiplier to 2, to get a higher resolution image, only the top-right quarter of the produced image contains the image created from the canvas.

[PNG image that is cutoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rWBK.png)

I've found resources online that say this *was* an issue in previous versions of fabric and I've seen others' workarounds, but nothing seems to fix my issue. Any help, advice or resources would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT
Maybe I should include an example of how I pass the JSON canvas to the server:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/designer';
http.open('POST', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
};
http.send(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else's reference, I added these two lines:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(2,2);
```

As well I also changed the dimensions to whatever dimensions I wanted the final image to be (in my case 1200x1200).